# Goerli ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'

Tags: python-3.x, solidity, brownie, erc721

I'm trying to deploy an NFT about Harry Potter following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p36tXHX1JD8&list=PLzmffB-8Vx5Twi0x5cRRdzyixrkJtaftJ&index=9&t=3s.

But when I run create_collectible.py I have an error:

ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.

***FULL ERROR OUTPUT***

```
File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/advanced_collectible/create_collectible.py", line 12, in main
    transaction = advanced_collectible.createCollectible(
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1861, in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1734, in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 644, in transfer
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 727, in _make_transaction
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
  File "brownie/exceptions.py", line 93, in __init__
    raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None
ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.
```

**create_collectible.py**

```
    from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, config
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_raffle, fund_with_link
import time

STATIC_SEED = 1234


def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
    advanced_collectible = AdvancedCollectible[len(AdvancedCollectible) - 1]
    fund_with_link(advanced_collectible.address)
    transaction = advanced_collectible.createCollectible(
        STATIC_SEED, "None", {"from": dev}
    )
    print("Waiting on second transaction...")
    # wait for the 2nd transaction
    transaction.wait(1)
    # time.sleep(35)
    requestId = transaction.events["RequestedCollectible"]["requestId"]
    token_id = advanced_collectible.requestIdToTokenId(requestId)
    raffle = get_raffle(advanced_collectible.tokenIdToRaffle(token_id))
    print("Houses of tokenId {} is {}".format(token_id, raffle))
```

**AdvancedCollectible.sol**

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract AdvancedCollectible is ERC721URIStorage, VRFConsumerBase {
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 public fee;
    uint256 public tokenCounter;

    enum Raffle {
        GRYFFINDOR,
        HUFFLEPUFF,
        RAVENCLAW,
        SLYTHERIN
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => address) public requestIdToSender;
    mapping(bytes32 => string) public requestIdToTokenURI;
    mapping(uint256 => Raffle) public tokenIdToRaffle;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) public requestToTokenId;

    event requestedCollectible(bytes32 indexed requestId);

    constructor(
        address _VRFCoordinator,
        address _LinkToken,
        bytes32 _keyhash
    ) VRFConsumerBase(_VRFCoordinator, _LinkToken) ERC721("Houses", "HOM") {
        keyHash = _keyhash;
        fee = 0.1 * 10**18; //0.1 LINK
        tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    function createCollectible(string memory tokenURI)
        public
        returns (bytes32)
    {
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
        requestIdToSender[requestId] = msg.sender; //When I create the request that request is associated with me
        requestIdToTokenURI[requestId] = tokenURI;
        emit requestedCollectible(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomNumber)
        internal
        override
    {
        address wizardOwner = requestIdToSender[requestId];
        string memory tokenURI = requestIdToTokenURI[requestId];
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
        _safeMint(wizardOwner, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        Raffle raffleHouse = Raffle(randomNumber % 4);
        //Need to assign that House raffle to this new token ID
        tokenIdToRaffle[newItemId] = raffleHouse;
        //Way to map the requestId to the tokenId
        requestToTokenId[requestId] = newItemId;
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    }

    function setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) public {
        require(
            _isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId),
            "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner not approved"
        );
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);
    }
}
```

**brownie-config.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.7.3
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.2
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.7.3'
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.2'
dotenv: .env
networks:
  default: development
  goerli:
    vrf_coordinator: '0x2Ca8E0C643bDe4C2E08ab1fA0da3401AdAD7734D'
    link_token: '0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB'
    keyhash: '0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15'
    fee: 2500000000000000000
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using alchemy, and re-trying the transaction there works fine. I have no idea why Goerli behaves this way.